# Add-AzureRmAccount : Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-runbook

I am running Azure Automation Runbook which has PowerShell script to restart the Azure Web App at defined scheduled. While test running the below script I am getting error:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName
$null = Add-AzureRmAccount ` 
    -ServicePrincipal ` 
    -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId ` 
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId ` 
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

$null = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId 'SubscriptionID'

Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName 'RGroupName' -Name 'webappname'
```

Error details:

Add-AzureRmAccount : Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'.

- $null = Add-AzureRmAccount
- CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzureRmAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand

Is this error related to having not enough access?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with your script on my side.

[image]

To fix the issue, change your script into the one below, it will work fine.

**Note**: Navigate to your automation account -> `Modules` -> make sure the modules `AzureRM.Profile`, `AzureRM.Websites` are existing, if not, click `Browse Gallery` to search them and import.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    $null = Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$null = Select-AzureRmContext -Subscription 'SubscriptionID'
Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName 'RGroupName' -Name 'webappname'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think I had few illegal characters as well while copying script from another document.